# Why does `git diff `autocomplete to a branch and not a file

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete

Posting this here in SO and not webapps StackExchange because I *know* that it pertains to `git`, but I'm not sure if it involves `GitHub` as well.

Let's say I have a repo `foo` on my machine at `/home/user/foo`, which is my current working directory, and I have a file in the repo: `/home/user/foo/main.sh`.

I'm working on the `master` branch (though I'm not sure it matters what branch I'm on), and I make some changes to `main.sh`.  I want to see the changes I made *only* to this file, so I enter:

```
$ git diff ma<tab>
```

Why does this autocomplete to `master` rather than `main.sh`?  Actually, more reasonably, I don't think it should autocomplete at all because with just the 2 letters `ma`, it's ambiguous.  I looked at the description on the `git diff` man page, but I don't see anything about one taking precedence over the other.

Comment: Nothing to do with GitHub at all. Connection to Git is a bit tenuous: all bash autocompletion is done in bash itself. It's up to whoever writes the autocompletion to decide how to implement it. Per xbonez answer below it appears they used `--` to decide whether to treat the next argument as a branch name (which is a valid commit selector) or a path name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man page for git-diff contains this:

> git diff [--options] [--] [path...]

So, if you're looking for git diff for a file/path, it's supposed to follow `--` (double hyphens). You'll find that if you do `git diff -- ma<tab>`, it will auto-complete to a filename, instead of a branch.

```
git diff $branch
git diff -- $filePath
```

Comment: Right, gotcha.  Yeah I read that in the man page.  I guess the answer then is that  even though `git diff $filePath` is incorrect, `git` "knows" what you mean at that point (if there is no branch with the same prefix), so it autocompletes to the file.